# php readdir and is_dir

Tags: php, directory

I am testing out the functions of directory handling. I have a fold/directory that contains the following:

0           File folder

false       File folder

my_pictures File folder

MVI_3094    mov file

img01       jpeg image

etc...

I wrote the following code to traverse the directory and print out specific resutls

```
$handle = opendir("files/");
while(($entry = readdir($handle)) !== false)
{
    if($entry == "." || $entry == "..")
    {
        continue;
    }
    if(is_dir($entry))
    {
        echo "Directory:$entry<br />";
    }
}
```

My only problem is that the second "if" statement does not output the results of

```
echo "Directory:$entry<br />";
```

even though the entry is a directory. I have checked the entry manually with the "var_dump" function and it returns true as a directory.

Any suggestions would help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this and check. Just a try...

```
$handle = opendir("files/");
while(($entry = readdir($handle)) !== false)
{
    if($entry == "." || $entry == "..")
    {
        continue;
    }
    elseif(is_dir("files/".$entry))
    {
        echo "Directory:$entry<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Works. But I'm still trying to figure out the logic of why it needs to be this way.

Comment: Becoz `is_dir` is relative. :) You have the directories inside the `files/`. :) Simple logic.

Answer (score 1):

$entry is relative... is_dir expects an absolute path.

Comment: Your answer works. But in the manual there is no mention of it needing an absolute path. It only states, "Path to the file. If filename is a relative filename, it will be checked relative to the current working directory. " I check the value manually like this: var_dump(is_dir($entry)) and it returned true.

Comment: The chdir() function will change the current dir in PHP.  Otherwise it doesn't change by readdir.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(is_dir("files/".$entry))
```

`readdir()` is just returning the filenames. Your code is therefore looking for the files in the current directory rather than the subdirectory.

Comment: But the manual states that if a filename is a directory (via is_dir) it should return true.

Comment: The problem is that it's the wrong filename. The filename you care about is `files/foo`, but `$entry` just contains `foo`.

Comment: I think I understand now. It's because I am using the opendir function which returns a handle and not a filename.

Answer (score 0):

This will just probe the basename of whatever directory entry:

```
 is_dir($entry)
```

The opendir() result list will be relative to the directory you gave for reading. So you need to use:

```
 is_dir("files/$entry")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php):

```
$iterator = new \DirectoryIterator(realpath('files/'));

foreach($iterator as $file){

  if($file->isDot())
    continue;

  if($file->isDir())
    printf('Directory: %s <br/>', $file->getRealPath());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in `elseif(is_dir($entry)) {`, `entry` is equal to some string like "file.txt" or "somedirectory", which isn't a path pointing to a file at all.  It needs to be "files/file.txt".

Try this:

```
$dir = "files/";
$handle = opendir($dir);
while(($entry = readdir($handle)) !== false)
{
    if($entry == "." || $entry == "..")
    {
        continue;
    }
    if(is_dir($dir.$entry))
    {
        echo "Directory:$entry<br />";
    }
}
```